# Error: Chunk.blocks: Use ChunkGroup.getBlocks() instead

Tags: webpack

I'm updating **webpack** from version 2 to version 4.
Got an error:

> Error: Chunk.blocks: Use ChunkGroup.getBlocks() instead

I tried to switch off plugins one by one and found that **HtmlWebpackPlugin** is the cause of the problem.

But still, don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

webpack 4's internal API's changed drastically, so you need to ensure that all of the plugins, loaders are updated as well. Many of them may be under major breaking changes so its best to look at their respective github repos to see.